# No me funcionan los botones en la actividad

Tags: android

Estoy siguiendo un tutorial para hacer una aplicación y el botón calcular no me funciona. Este botón, al indicar una cantidad en el inputBill y pulsar en el botón debería de salirme un texto con la propina calculada, pero no hace nada.

a continuación mis elementos en el layout.

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:hint="@string/main.hint.bill"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/inputBill"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/main.button.submit"
        android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
        android:layout_alignParentTop = "true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/inputBill"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/inputBill"

        />
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/txtTip"
        android:layout_below="@id/separator"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        />
```

Dejo el código que tengo hasta ahora,

```
@BindView(R.id.inputBill)
    EditText inputBill;
    @BindView(R.id.btnSubmit)
    Button btnSubmit;
    @BindView(R.id.inputPercentage)
    EditText inputPercentage;
    @BindView(R.id.btnIncrease)
    Button btnIncrease;
    @BindView(R.id.btnDecrease)
    Button btnDecrease;
    @BindView(R.id.btnClear)
    Button btnClear;
    @BindView(R.id.separator)
    View separator;
    @BindView(R.id.txtTip)
    TextView txtTip;


    private final static int TIP_STEP_CHANGE = 1;
    private final static int DEFAULT_TIP_PERCENTAGE = 10;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

    }


    @OnClick(R.id.btnSubmit)
    public void handleClickSubmit() {
      //  hideKeyBoard();
        String strInputTotal = inputBill.getText().toString().trim();
        if (!strInputTotal.isEmpty()) {
            double total = Double.parseDouble(strInputTotal);
            int tipPercentage = getTipPercentage();
            double tip = total * (tipPercentage / 100d);

            String strTip = String.format(getString(R.string.global_message_tip), tip);
            // log.d("no se crea la variable strtip");
            Log.d("txtTip", "error encontrado");
            txtTip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txtTip.setText(strTip);

        }
    }
```

no tengo errores en el codigo, compila pero algo mal estoy haciendo y no se el que...

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hola te adjunto pantallazo del logcat. uno de los errores que tenia session 'app' error lauching activity ya no lo tengo al desactivar en settings el auto run....

Comment: agrega tu método getTipPercentage(). No se muestra ningun texto en txtTip?

Comment: Esta línea te la hace? Log.d("txtTip", "error encontrado");

Comment: ¿Has pensado en usar el .setOnClick?

Comment: yo se que el post es viejo pero tengo ese mismo inconveniente, lo resolverian ?

Comment: @Eduardo te recomiendo que trates de editar esta pregunta, añadiendo cualquier información que pueda aclararla y que cosas has probado. De esa manera, esta pregunta se "reactivará" y es posible que alguien trate de resolverla. Un saludo y bienvenido a [es.so]

Answer (score 0):

Veo que usas ButterKnife, y veo que tu botón llama el método `handleClickSubmit()`

```
   @OnClick(R.id.btnSubmit)
   public void handleClickSubmit() {
      //  hideKeyBoard();
        String strInputTotal = inputBill.getText().toString().trim();
        if (!strInputTotal.isEmpty()) {
            double total = Double.parseDouble(strInputTotal);
            int tipPercentage = getTipPercentage();
            double tip = total * (tipPercentage / 100d);

            String strTip = String.format(getString(R.string.global_message_tip), tip);
            // log.d("no se crea la variable strtip");
            Log.d("txtTip", "error encontrado");
            txtTip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txtTip.setText(strTip);

        }
    }
```

Una causa me parece que el valor de `getTipPercentage()` asegura no sea 0 por eso no se obtendría un valor para calcular la propina.

Asegura también la definición de tu formato sea correcto, debería ser algo similar a :

```
<string name="global_message_tip" formatted="false">Propina: %.2f%n</string>
```

Comment: me sigue sin funcionar, he revisado el metodo getTipPercentage() pero no he encontrado ningun error y he modificado el formato en <string name="global...
gracias elenasys
pero no funciona.

el nombre de algunos metodos me salen en gris y otros en azul. esto es por que algunos se estan usando y otros no? puede el error estar por ejemplo en el plugin butterknife?

Comment: Rafa primeramente agrega un breakpoint dentro del método handleClickSubmit() y realiza debug para verificar se activa cuando das clic. el metodo handleClickSubmit() ondica que no es usado?

Comment: $ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/calcursoedxleccion0.cal"
 pkg: /data/local/tmp/calcursoedxleccion0.cal
Success


$ adb shell am start -n "calcursoedxleccion0.cal/calcursoedxleccion0calculadorademo0.calculadorademo.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Unexpected error while executing: am start -n "calcursoedxleccion0.cal/calcursoedxleccion0calculadorademo0.calculadorademo.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error while Launching activity

Comment: que me sale el error Error while Launching activity

Comment: OK! puedes ver que despliega en tu LogCat, si obtienes ese mensaje de error podríamos saber que causa el problema.